# Str_Replace After File_Get_Contents

Tags: php, domdocument, str-replace

I'm pulling a page from another website using DomDocument.

The page that is returned has a few of the same links. These links all have the same path: https://example.com/team-registration/

What I would like to do is overwrite these links so they go to a different path: https://mobile.example.com/registration-team.php when the page is returned.

```
$url = "https://example.com/index.php";
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents($url));
$div = $doc->getElementById('upcoming_league_dates');
str_replace("<a href='https://example.com/team-registration/'", "<a href='https://mobile.example.com/registration-team.php'", $div);
echo $doc->saveHTML($div);
```

I tried str_replace but it is throwing an error.

UPDATED CODE

Here's the updated code according to @Ally Shairu's example:

```
$url = "https://pugetsoundbasketball.com/index.php";
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents($url));
$div = $doc->getElementById('upcoming_league_dates');
$value = str_replace("<a href='https://example.com/team-registration/'", "<a href='https://mobile.example.com/registration-team.php'", $div->nodeValue);
$div->nodeValue = $value;
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
echo $html;
```

Unfortunately this pulls the entire page rather than the "upcoming_league_dates" div only. Actually, it seems to display all the content from that page except for the "upcoming_league_dates" div.

When I try this it fails also:

$html = $doc->saveHTML();

Comment: care to share the error?

Comment: Not sure about your error, but you might want to assign the return value of `str_replace` to `$div`.

Comment: `str_replace` returns the modified string. it doesn't do an in-place replacement, and you can't just do `$div = str_replace`, since you'd be trashing the DOMElement that gEBI() returns anyways.

Comment: Catchable Fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in.....

Comment: Any other suggestions? Ive tried all the solutions given

Answer (score 0):

str_replace function returns the modified string or array. You are not saving that value anywhere? I guess this might be the problem, if not, share the errors.

Edit:
Since you have shared the error I think you need to get the nodeValue try this $div->nodeValue. This will work if your html is valid.

var_dump($div) to see what are you actually getting.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How do I alter the code though to add in $div->nodeValue (what line do I change?) Thanks again

Comment: Replace this 
`str_replace("<a href='https://example.com/team-registration/'", "<a href='https://mobile.example.com/registration-team.php'", $div);`
with this one 
`$div = str_replace("<a href='https://example.com/team-registration/'", "<a href='https://mobile.example.com/registration-team.php'", $div->nodeValue);`

Comment: thanks.. now I get: Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects parameter 1 to be DOMNode, string given in.. doesnt load after the warning

Comment: var_dump($div) comes through but with no HTML of course

Comment: Add these lines
`$value = str_replace("<a href='https://example.com/team-registration/'", "<a href='https://mobile.example.com/registration-team.php'", $div->nodeValue);
$div->nodeValue = $value;
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
`

Comment: It should, the $html variable is now a new page with an modified link, I believe that was not even your question. It was related to str_replace and that is fixed :) Peace.

Comment: does it need to be $doc->saveHTML($value) ? without $value it returns the whole page..